# Can you select which line to write to with a BufferedWriter?

Tags: java, bioinformatics, bufferedwriter

I've got a program where I'm sorting data and creating percentage values from this data. I'm using a [java.io.BufferedWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/BufferedWriter.html) to write to my files.

My problem is that once I've read in my data files and printed the wanted information to my new file, I can't add my calculated percentage values on my existing lines, only the end of the file.

eg. I have

```
12 F 56 Bovine
...
...
NewPercentages
%%
%%
```

I want

```
12 F 56 Bovine %%
...            %%
```

Comment: You can add or remove whatever you desire; just add some String-handling code in between the reading and the writing, the details will depend much on the actual input and desired output data structure, as well as your current code, something we don't know much about. Please check out the [help] and the [ask] to see how to improve this question.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to stackoverflow.com! I edited your question to clarify some details. Please review my edits and re-edit as required.

Comment: BufferedWriter writes sequentially, so you cannot add some data in the middle of the file after you have written everything. You can, however, postpone the writing of the output file, and write the additional information when it's appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are currently printing out some lines of data, and you want to change the lines that you have already printed.

This is not possible using Java's `BufferedWriter`. As a matter of fact, it's not possible with most I/O libraries I am familiar with - it seems you have misunderstood how Java's `BufferedWriter` (and by extension, output in general) works.

The fundamental assumption with `BufferedWriter` (and most other APIs for writing output, both in Java and elsewhere is): **You only send your final, complete output.**  Once you sent output, it's out of your control. It will be sent to its final destination, which may mean being written to an output file, printed on a console/terminal window, sent to different computer, whatever. So there is no "taking back" or "editing" - like a letter you posted, the data is off to its destination.

---

To address your problem: If you want to change/amend the data you are printing, you need to **delay printing**. You need to prepare your complete output, and only then print it out.

There are various ways to do this. The simplest is to just prepare everything in memory, by creating a list of values to print (using e.g. a `java.util.List`). Then you can go through your output data as often as you like, and print it off when it is finished.

There are many ways to do this (directly creating output strings, creating "data holder" objects that you print later, ...) - this will depend on your problem.

I hope that helps you along. If you still have trouble, post your code along with the problem you have as a new question. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. I kinda figures that was the case. I ended up just deciding to write it to a different file and process then together later when I needed to. Which worked fine. Thanks again for the help

Comment: Yes, using a temporary file is another common solution.